# Finding if a number is the power of 2 in Scheme

Tags: scheme, bitwise-operators

I'm fairly new to Scheme and am attempting to learn it on my own from scratch. I'm stuck on the syntax of this problem. I know that if I want to find out if a number is a power of 2, in C for instance, I would simply do:

```
return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
```

which would return true or false. How would I be able to convert this into a couple simple lines in Scheme?

Answer (score 6):

I'll give you a hint since you're trying to learn the language.

Scheme has a function called `(bitwise-and ...)` which is equivalent to the `&` operator in C (there is also `(bitwise-xor ...)`, `(bitwise-not ..)`, etc., which do the expected thing).

(Here is the documentation of the [`(bitwise-and ...)`](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._bitwise-and%29%29) function)

Given that, would you be able to translate what you've written in your question into Scheme code?

N.B: For a problem like this, you really don't need to resort to bitwise operations when using Scheme.  Realistically, you should be writing a (<strike>possibly</strike> probably tail) recursive function that will compute this for you.

Comment: I see that the code was written out as an answer here after I posted.  Oh well.

Comment: I saw this first before I refreshed the page and saw the rest, and it did help, so thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a built in bitwise operator.

```
(define (pow2? x)
  (= (bitwise-and x (- x 1))
     0))
```

Comment: (You should probably name the function `(pow2? ..)` rather than `(pow2 ..)` since they imply different things.

Comment: The name should be pow2? , because it is a predicate.

Comment: @Andrew, @Dima: I'm also fairly new to Scheme, so I wasn't aware of this convention.  I fixed my code.  Thanks.

Comment: This makes sense. Since the bitwise operator is built in, do I not need to import any libraries in order for it to leave me alone about errors?

Comment: @Evan: I don't know if it's built in to every Scheme.  I'm using DrScheme with the language set to Module and not getting any errors or warnings.

Comment: Depends.  Different scheme implementations have very annoying subtle differences.  Try it out.

Comment: The math jargon for “power of two” is “impolite number.”

Comment: sgm, "politeness" refers to the property of a number of being able to be represented by a sum of consecutive integers; it just happens that impolite numbers and powers of two are the same set.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme also has [biwise operators](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/s48/0.57/manual/s48manual_37.html).

But if you really want to develop your scheme skills, you should write a function that decides if an integer is a power of 2 by recursively dividing it by 2 until you are left with either 2 or with an odd number.  This would be very inefficient, but really cool nonetheless.

Comment: It would be shorter if I wrote it in Scheme, but that would have deprived you of the joy of coding it yourself.